# Unable to deploy project to Heroku using Python 3.9 or 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

Currently, Heroku supports multiple versions of Python as per their documentation. However, I run into an error when I try to deploy a project while including a `runtime.txt`:

```
Requested runtime (cat runtime.txt python-3.9.0) 
is not available for this stack (Heroku-20).
```

Within the `runtime.txt` I have:

```py
cat runtime.txt
python-3.9.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Within the `runtime.txt` I have:
>
> ```
> cat runtime.txt
> python-3.9.0
> ```

That file should only contain

```
python-3.9.0
```

[`cat`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html), short for "concatenate", is a command that you can run on some operating systems (Linux, Unix, likely macOS, maybe others) to show the contents of a file. You probably saw some documentation that said something like

```
$ cat runtime.txt
python-3.9.0
```

which is supposed to mean "if you run `cat runtime.txt` you should see `python-3.9.0`".

Edit your `runtime.txt` to remove the `cat` line, commit, and redeploy.